# Deploy web application on IIS with FAKE

Tags: web-deployment, f#-fake

Im trying to deploy asp.net mvc application to IIS on a remote PC with Fake.
I can build everything successfully. I also make nuget package of my webapp as Fake.Deploy
use nuget packages for deployment. but what should I add in my fsx script in nuget to stop IIS, then move the bin and content of a new site into virtual directory and then start IIS?
I dont want to use octopus deploy, so some fake script or  cmd line would be just fine.

Comment: You can write any .NET code in `*.fsx` file. For example if you need to star/stop IIS:`open System.Diagnostics;
Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo("iisreset.exe", " /stop"));
Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo("iisreset.exe", " /start"));`

Comment: I need it for testing purposes only, so plain xcopy worked fine. If you add an answer I would mark it as correct one as it answer my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write any `.NET`(`F#`) code in `*.fsx` file.
As far as I know you should be able to reference `FakeLib.dll` and use [all available helper functions](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/index.html)

```
#r "FakeLib.dll"

open System.Diagnostics
open Fake

// Stop IIS process
Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo("iisreset.exe", " /stop"))
// Copy missing/updated files
XCopy "your source directory path" "your destination directory path"
// Start IIS process
Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo("iisreset.exe", " /start"))
```

Comment: stopping IIS to update a website doesn't seem to be the best approach (because you could be serving errors to customers currently using the site); isn't there a technique to create a new website programmatically, and then swap the old version with the new one?

Comment: If you have availability concerns, you're likely to run on two machines behind a load balancer.